# What's the idiomatic way to get the last element from a generated array?

Tags: javascript, one-liner

I want to get the last element from a generated array in a single line, is there a better way to do it?

I was thinking assign the array to `foo` then immediatly assign the last element of `foo` to itself again but it doesn't work:

```js
function* getArray() {
  yield* [1, 2, 3];
}

let foo = (foo = [...getArray()], foo[foo.length - 1]);

console.log(foo); // 3?
```

This works but it's calling `getArray()` twice which is quite unnecessary.

```js
function* getArray() {
  yield* [1, 2, 3];
}

let foo = [...getArray()][[...getArray()].length - 1];

console.log(foo); // 3
```

Comment: Use [`.at(-1)`](//github.com/tc39/proposal-relative-indexing-method), `.at(-2)`, etc. which is also mentioned here: [Get the last item in an array](/a/61847169/4642212). Use this [polyfill](//github.com/tc39/proposal-relative-indexing-method#polyfill). I’d recommend checking the existence of the method before adding it. Alternatively, `.slice(-1)[0]`, `.slice(-2)[0]`, etc. are idiomatic.

Comment: storing the whole generator in memory just to pull the last element is suboptimal

Comment: @georg There’s also the [Double-Ended Iterator and Destructuring proposal](//github.com/tc39/proposal-deiter).

Comment: @SebastianSimon: in up-to-date javascript, this would be as simple as `for(x of iter) {}; return x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just [`.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) it

> The pop() method removes the last element from an array and returns that element.

```js
function* getArray() {
  yield* [1, 2, 3];
}

let foo = [...getArray()].pop()
console.log(foo); // 3

let bar = [...getArray()].slice(-2)[0]
console.log(bar); // 2

let baz = [...getArray()].splice(-2, 1)[0]
console.log(baz); // 2
```

Comment: Oh... I feel like an idiot now... thanks so much! But I about an arbitrary index? Such as the second last one?

Comment: let foo = [...getArray()][1] ?

Comment: `.slice(-2)[0]` if you want second to last and don't know the length

Comment: Ah I see, why I didn't think of this way. Thank you so much, again!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it in a single statement:

```
[...getArray()].reverse()[0]
```